# Where/how is Yarn's "Application Type" defined?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

If one submits new jobs to an Apache YARN cluster the status page  usually indicates how the job was actually submitted (among other things):
[image]

```
Application Type: SPARK
```

This indicates that the user most likely used spark-submit to issue a new job to the resource manager.

Is it's possible to change the value of that string through a parameter in the same way it is possible to change the name of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application type is set when the yarn application context is set up by Spark.

AFAIK, it is not possible to change it means of some configuration. If it really matters, you will have to override it in source.

Implementation below,
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/01c3dfab158d40653f8ce5d96f57220297545d5b/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L241

Comment: Tyvm - that's what I was looking for!